# AWS RDS: How to access/connect to RDS MySql DB From localhost

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, rds, mysql-connect

I am very new to Amazon Web Services, I have created Mysql DB on RDS and stored some data.

Now i want to connect to RDS db from localhost(which is in running on my desktop) ,Tried as fallow in my PHP connection.

```
$con = mysql_connect("XXXX.XXXXX.XX-XX-X.rds.amazonaws.com:3306", "XXX", "XXX");
```

But getting error as fallows

> Could not connect: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'awsniti.XXXX.rds.amazonaws.com'

Also tried giving my local IP address to Inbounds of Security Group. But couldn't connect.

googled a lot, but not able to find right answer.

Please help me with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the internet IP of your local network/machine on the security group associated with your RDS database should work. But I prefer to create a SSH tunnel through a server that I already gave access to the database. This way you don't have to care about the security group configuration every time you need to connect from a different IP address.

If you are on Linux or OSX you can run locally
`ssh -f user@your-web-server.com -L 3306:XXXX.XXXXX.XX-XX-X.rds.amazonaws.com:3306 -N` and then connect `localhost:3306` from PHP to access the RDS database. If you are on Windows it's also possible to create a tunnel using Putty (http://bit.ly/1GQmaYo)

Comment: Hi.. After i create a SSH tunnel , Can i able to connect to RDS DB through PHP Connect ?

Comment: Yes you can connect locally to the remote RDS database.  After you establish the tunnel you can connect as if it was running in your local machine `$con = mysql_connect("localhost:3306", "XXX", "XXX");`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Now i got one more requirement , Here i want to access local database from PHP file which is in EC2 server.. Is there anyway ?